# How to access my saved files on a persistent LiveUSB?

Tags: mount, live-usb, squashfs

I have been using a persistent mode USB when the hard disk of my laptop crashed. I like to mount the USB files on another computer running Ubuntu 12.10. From what I found after internet search, the file system is saved as squashfs file. The only squashfs file was /casper/filesystem.squashfs . I mounted this file using disks application (it used /dev/loop0 device ). However, I could not find the files that I had saved while running from the USB.

The files were saved in /home/ubuntu/Downloads. The mounted filesystem has no folder under the home directory. What should I do to retrieve the file on this computer. I do not have the permission to reboot this computer from the persistent USB. I just need the files saved inside the persistent file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filesystem.squashfs` is mounted read only. The files you have modified/created are written to `casper-rw`. Mount it with:

```
mkdir /tmp/casper
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/casper-rw /tmp/casper
```

Comment: In newer versions of Ubuntu, USBs are automatically mounted to `/media/<user>/<drive-label>/casper-rw`