# extract files from filesystem.squashfs file

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem

I have installed Xubuntu on a USB stick and created some files. Later there was a problem with Xubuntu, so I made a backup and re-installed it.

The wayt I made the backup, isn't exacly the right way of doing it (I'm not so familiar with this subject :) ):

I cnnected the USB stick to a running Windows computer and just copied all the files I found there form the USB stick ("My Computer") to the windows computer.

The files I copied are some folders (e.g. `.disk`, `boot`, `casper`, `dists`, `EFI` and some more.) and some files (e.g. `casper-rw`, `md5sum.txt`, `menu.c32`, `README.diskdefines`, `syslinux.cfg` and more.)

Now I want to recover some files from my desktop in Xubuntu in order to edit them in Windows or even linux.

I notices in the folder `casper` there are few files:

- filesystem.manifest
- filesystem.manifest-remove
- filesystem.size
- **filesystem.squashfs**
- initrd.lz
- vmlinuz.efi

The biggest file there, **filesystem.squashfs**, weights almost 1 GB, so I have a reason to beleive that this file contains my files from Xubuntu.

How can I exctract them? I can use linux (I have a new, working version of Xubuntu on the same USB stick, while the "backup" is located on the `C` drive of the hosting computer)

Thanks!!

Comment: Basically you need to mount the file. Please read http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/whatis.html  and then http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80305/mounting-a-squashfs-filesystem-in-read-write

Comment: Thanks! I installed the squashfs tools and I'm trying this right now. It takes a lot of time, (157627 files ;) ) but from what I can see now, it looks just like what I needed. Thank you so much! I'll update you when it's over.

Comment: ... :'( the `home` folder is empty... Perhaps the file I found is... Some sort of initial backup the installer created automatically. Perhaps there's a different file which actually has **my** files?

Comment: How did you "install" onto the USB? I usually see `filesystem.squashfs` as part of the live ISO, and "casper" part of the persistent feature, I think `casper-rw` used to be the "filesystem in a file" that stored your changed/personal files...

Comment: The files you create in a LiveUSB are saved in the `casper-rw` file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access my saved files on a persistent LiveUSB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/311508/how-to-access-my-saved-files-on-a-persistent-liveusb)

Comment: Xen2050- i ran a diskless virtual machine with an iso as a "cd drive", and booted from the "cd".

Comment: Eric Carvalho - looks like what I need... I'll check it out soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your overall question, and comments like:

- *i ran a diskless virtual machine with an iso as a "cd drive", and booted from the "cd".*

It sounds to me like you may have only been running "live" with no persistence. Especially given the iso in the VM's "cd drive", I'm suspecting there might not be any saved files to recover, unless the VM saved them somehow...

But, maybe using a USB it did let you save persistent data. If there is a `casper-rw` file then you should be able to mount it and take a look, as Eric's comment suggests, with

```
mkdir /tmp/casper
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/casper-rw /tmp/casper
```

Comment: I **do** have persistence, sorry I didn't mention it. Where can I find this `casper-rw` file?

Comment: Ok. Then it should be in the files you copied, you mentioned *"some files (e.g. casper-rw,..."*

Comment: Dude, you saved my life! It's amazing! always fun to learn something new :)

Comment: Actually... hold on.. I copied the files, they contain `ry_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt, mozilla/GeoTrust_Universal_CA.crt, mozilla/GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.crt, mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt, mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.crt, mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_`.... WHY???

Comment: I guess it's my fault, because the XFCE config files were recovered correctly... I don't know why it happened to these files, but fine. thanks again! Next time I'll know not to create files on linux without Dropbox or some other automatic backup services.

Comment: Always best to have a good backup of important data (on a hard drive, another USB/DVD, online... encrypted is good too)